# Изменить background-color у select2 элемента при инициализации

Tags: php, yii2, select2, kartik

Собственно, как изменить фон у элемента kartik\select2\Select2 (не раскрывающего списка, а просто видимого инпута), без js и css? Как нибудь через опции..

```
Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => [],
    'options' => ['style' => 'background-color: #000;'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
    ],
]
```

Думал, в опциях, как в примере, но, к сожалению, не подходит.

Comment: Пришлось пока сделать через css: #id-element .select2-selection {
        background-color: #000 !important;
    }